# Livecode repeat command

Tags: livecode

I have the bellow code and I want to complete the following.
I have a group with some fields.
I have 2 Variables. Variable 1 with names from fields and variable 2 with the values.
I want to set the text for the fields in the group to variable 2.
Line 1 from Var 1 = field name 1 -- Var 2 line 1 = value
Line 2 from Var 1 = field name 2 -- Var 2 Line 2 = value

```
repeat with x=1 to the number of flds of grp "flds_grp"
          add 1 to counter
          put the short name of  fld x & cr after fldNames
     end repeat

     set the itemdel to comma
     put 0 into myCounter
     repeat for each line f in fldNames
          repeat for each line t in tvalues



          end repeat
     end repeat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variable `counter`but it seems that you don't need this variable.

To set the text of field f to the value of variable t, use the following syntax:

```
set the text of field f to t
```

Comment: i have try it but the repeat loop is inside f so change the same field with the values from var 2.i want..<br>
I want to change  var 1 line 1 <> var 2 line 1<br>var 1 line 2 <> var 2 line 2 and etc

Comment: No idea what you're trying to write. Perhaps you update your question with additional explanations.

Comment: OK. And in what way is my solution different from what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The right method have be answered from Sparkout in the Livecode forums.

```
repeat with x=1 to the number of flds of group "grp-A"
   put line x of tValues into field x of group "grp-A"
end repeat
```